# Is the RC2014 on topic or not?

Tags: discussion, scope

The RC2014 is a computer based on a Z80, and designed to run Microsoft BASIC

From the front page of their website,

> RC2014 is a simple 8 bit Z80 based modular computer originally built to run Microsoft BASIC. It is inspired by the home built computers of the late 70s and computer revolution of the early 80s.

And it feels like something that could have been around in 1981 or whenever. But it's a recent, and currently available, computer, with new hardware and software developments on it all the time. Maybe some feel that this disqualifies it as retro. But questions about the RC2014 are (at least occasionally) well-received.

[Is there a way to boot CP/M automatically on a RC2014?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/24896/is-there-a-way-to-boot-cp-m-automatically-on-a-rc2014) is voted off-topic.

[How does the serial port on the RC2014 get addressed?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/22285/how-does-the-serial-port-on-the-rc2014-get-addressed) was not.

[How can SPI be used with a Z80 CPU to control an RFM95 LoRa module?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/24834/how-can-spi-be-used-with-a-z80-cpu-to-control-an-rfm95-lora-module) also was not.

Can we reach a consensus?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 thanks for the edit! I didn't know you could do links that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it should be **on topic**.

- The primary technology involved - Z80, 5V TTL, etc. - is not widely used (if at all) in any modern computers, even if it is still available for repairs, etc.
- CP/M and other operating systems available for this type of device are considered Retrocomputing.
- Serial ports for such a device should be on topic, provided they are RS-232 or similar. Interfacing a USB port would not be on topic.
- SPI is itself an old technology (1979 according to Wikipedia). While it is available for modern machines too, interfacing SPI to an 8-bit Z80 should be on topic.

If a device like this was implemented in software (a.k.a., emulation) or with an FPGA instead of an actual Z80 chip, then I would consider it off-topic.

Comment: I'm not sure about your last point; the minimig is on topic, why not Hypothetical Z80 Implementation? Well, I think it comes down to what the actual question is.